# Is there any magic link like [faq] to use in comments for the page listing the topics for which questions can be asked?

Tags: support, off-topic, help-center, magic-links

When I close a question as off-topic, I generally add a link to the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) with a quote of the description that applies to the asked question. (For example, "Implementing a functionality, or a layout, seen in a site for which only a screenshot, or the site URL is provided.")

I tried using `[faq#on-topic]`, but that doesn't point to the right page.

Is there any magic link I could use in comments for the page listing the topics for which questions can be asked? If there isn't any, consider this a feature request.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes there is such magic link, I had to view the Source of the original faq page which has client side redirection to the new Help Center.

Cutting to the chase, it's: `[faq#questions]` now. :)
(Which redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

To make this more complete, here is the full list:

```
#vote-differences ==> /help/whats-meta
#askpatents ==> /help/whats-ask-patents
#bounty ==> /help/bounty
#close ==> /help/closed-questions
#declined-closed ==> /help/whats-meta
#deletion ==> /help/deleted-questions
#dontask ==> /help/dont-ask
#editing ==> /help/editing
#etiquette ==> /help/behavior
#flagging ==> /help/flags
#found-prior-art ==> /help/found-prior-art
#get-legal-advice ==> /help/get-legal-advice
#good-question ==> /help/good-patent-question
#howtoask ==> /about
#login ==> /help/why-register
#prior-art ==> /help/prior-art
#promotion ==> /help/behavior
#questions ==> /help/on-topic
#reputation ==> /help/whats-reputation
#searching ==> /help/searching
#signatures ==> /help/behavior
#tag-use ==> /help/tag-use
#what-about ==> /help/more-help
#what-questions-not ==> /help/dont-ask
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer! `:)`

Comment: Cheers, luckily they made the redirection client side so we can analyze it. ;)