# What other magiclinks would people find useful?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, magic-links

I think that [magiclinks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/138432) are an excellent feature, but I wonder if there might be room for a few more.

In particular, I would like to see magic links for the different sections on the [What kind of behavior is expected of users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) page.

I would love `[be-nice]` to be replaced with [Be nice](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior#be-nice) and `[self-promotion]` to be replaced with [Avoid overt self-promotion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior#self-promotion) <sub>(with appropriate page anchors being added to the page)</sub>

Would others find an extension of the *magiclinks* feature useful, and if so, what links would you like to see?

Comment: What about a `[skeet]` magic link?

Comment: Ignore this comment. just testing a few magiclinks... [faq#bounty] [edit] [SO] [meta] [math.SE] I'm done for now.

Comment: @hjpotter92 - Yes, on meta the `[meta]` magiclink doesn't work but the `[main]` does and vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

There are already a [large collection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183789/145951) of items that can be linked in the <strike>FAQ</strike> help system using magic-links. While these links still work, everything is a little discombobulated right now there is an [outstanding request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183131/145951) to update the magic links. This is partially done in that `[help]` works instead of `[faq]` but incomplete in that all the deep linkable sections have not been updated yet.

Yes, I agree it would be nice if the individual sections were linkable with their titles, but I think it should be done matching the URL of the help pages. `[help/deleted-answers]` for example should create a titled link [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).